# Powershell - If statement, returning count result in a popup

Tags: powershell, if-statement, popup

i'm learning powershell by trying to automate some jobs/problems i encounter at work.  I wanted to count periodically if there are any .ERR file(s) in a particular folder and if there was, create a popup box with the quantity of that count result.

So i created a script to count the files in the folder, no problem.  I also created a script to generate a popup box but when i combine the two in an If statement i no longer get a popup box and my powershell console returns a 1 after running the script?

My script is as follows:

```
$errchk = Write-Host ( Get-ChildItem c:\PS\test\*.ERR | Measure-Object ).Count
$str1 = "Number of .ERR files: "
If ($errchk -gt 0)
    {$wsh = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
    $wsh.Popup($str1+$errchk,0,"WDServer Error",0)}
```

Comment: For starters, remove `Write-Host`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
$errchk = Write-Host ( Get-ChildItem c:\PS\test\*.ERR | Measure-Object ).Count
```

This is the problem. `Write-Host` specifically means "write to the console". The command has no standard output. It skips output entirely and logically it's equivalent to:

```bsh
Write-Host ( Get-ChildItem c:\PS\test\*.ERR | Measure-Object ).Count
$errchk = $null
```

In general, you want to avoid using `Write-Host`. It's useful *exactly* when you want to write text to the console and you want to *prevent* the output from ever being assigned.

Second, essentially all object collections in PowerShell have a `Count` property. You don't need to pass them through `Measure-Object` to figure it out. So, you could do this:

```bsh
$errchk = (Get-ChildItem c:\PS\test\*.ERR).Count
if ($errchk -gt 0) {
    $WSH = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $WSH.Popup("Number of .ERR files: $errchk",0,'WDServer Error',0)
}
```

In general, I would not use COM objects at all, would not use WScript any longer, and would avoid GUI components as much as you can. You could accomplish your script like so, and it does what you really need:

```bsh
$errchk = (Get-ChildItem c:\PS\test\*.ERR).Count
if ($errchk -gt 0) {
    "Number of .ERR files: $errchk"
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you for taking the time to explain it. Really appreciate the help.